# Change default HTML5 video player in iOS 16

Tags: html, ios, iphone, html5-video, ios16

I have a video sharing website that has a high percentage of iOS users. With the [latest updates](https://9to5mac.com/2022/06/23/ios-16-video-player/) to the native video player in iOS 16, the user experience has diminished somewhat.

Previously the video on a website would display like this:

[image]

Currently in iOS 16 it displays like this:

[image]

Notice the dimming, more obtrusive controls and less video content being shown whilst these controls are active. These controls do disappear after a couple of seconds, but it does lessen the user experience.

The website in question hosts very short videos, typically 5-10 seconds long. It also has a slideshow type navigation experience. You can click 'next' to the next video in the 'reel'. The next video is loaded dynamically without a full page reload. It is setup this way for a smoother user experience. Every time a user clicks 'next' to the next video, the controls come up on the screen, blocking most of the video for 2 seconds - which is around 10-20% of the entire video. You can see why this would be problematic and a bad user experience.

My question is, is there a workaround? Can I define custom controls for HTML5 video and have an iOS 16 phone honor those controls? The video player controls on iOS 15 were just fine.

Thanks

Comment: _"Can I define custom controls for HTML5 video and have an iOS 16 phone honor those controls?"_ You can test that yourself at: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_met_play_pause. If working then go ahead an make own control icons etc (png, svg, whatever as long as it's clickable by mouse...)

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately default 'dimming' and controls on the video remain.

Comment: You must remove the `controls` option from your `<video>` tag setup.

Comment: @VC.One Perfect! That's what I'm after. If you submit an answer I'll mark it as accepted.